# Getting an error `xlValues` is not defined when Cells format to the others

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I am trying to copy the format of an Cell say here "A1" to the all cells of the first row using VBScript,but getting an error `xlValues` is not defined.

**CODE**

```
  ob3.Range("A1").Copy
  ob3.Range("A1").EntireRow.PasteSpecial(xlValues) 'error here for that constants
```

Can you help me here?

Thanks,

Comment: @safetyOtter could you please give me the link from where Such an Excel constant values can be obtained?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As VBScript does not know about Excel's constant, you'll have to define them yourself:

```
Const xlValues = 123 ' <-- replace 123 with the correct value for your version of Excel
```

Comment: Could you give me a link from where I can get such Excel constant values? I am using Excel 2010

Comment: @VBSlover: use your Excel/VBA documentation, the Object Explorer, and the Immediate Window.

Comment: I am not getting that option which you asked me to do. Even I google it,might be I am not searching proper way! So if you have please share link.

Comment: I got the way how to do that. This is as follows - `Press F2 in the Visual Basic Editor to start it, type your search term in the search box, and press Enter or click the Search button (the binoculars).`

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of constants here: http://techsupt.winbatch.com/ts/T000001033005F9.html

These are for Excel 97 but in your case (xlValues) the constant hasn't changed (-4163).

With

```
Const xlValues = -4163
...
ob3.Range("A1").Copy
ob3.Range("A1").EntireRow.PasteSpecial(xlValues)
```

you shouldn't get an error anymore

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
ob3.Range("A1").Copy
ob3.Range("A1").EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

Comment: could you please give me the link from where Such an Excel constant values can be obtained?