# Selecting Excel Cells with data in VBScript

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have been trying to manipulate Excel files with only VBScript code. It's a stand-alone VBScript that is opening and closing excel files. Problem is with `Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select` code. When I run this code in excel macro it is selecting all rows with continuous data in a particular cell. As I want it to do. Problem is when i try to run this code from VBScript. Type of file is `.vbs`

I have created Excel object: `Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` inside the script. and code `objExcel.Range("A5").select` is selecting the right cell. But `objExcel.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select` is doing nothing. It is the same functionality when you hold `shift + ctrl` and press down arrow in excel. When I record macro in excel and run it there are also no problems, the same code is running in VBA normally. Rows are getting selected. Only issue is when I convert that code to stand-alone VBScript that nothing is happening.

I need a way to select continuous cells with data in it. Same like `ctrl+shift` + down,up,left,right. If you know any other way of achieving it I'm OK with it.

Comment: Try using `-4121` instead of `xlDown`.

Comment: @BigBen wouldn't encourage the use of "magic numbers", just define the constant in the code `Const xlDown = -4121`.

Comment: @Lankymart agreed, much cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VBScript` doesn't understand the constants used by the `VBA` setup such as `xlDown`.

You need to reference the actual value for `xlDown` instead, which you can get from the [MS Docs site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel(enumerations))

In this specific instance you mention, the constant value is `-4121` so your command in `vbscript` would be:

```
objExcel.Range(Selection, Selection.End(-4121)).Select i
```

However, you should always try to avoid using Select in VBA/VBScript due to the performance hit, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) for more info

Comment: @IGRACH Here's the specific [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldirection) for the `xlDirection` enum.

Comment: It's still not selecting.


`objExcel.Workbooks(File_Name).Activate
  objExcel.Range("A5").select
  objExcel.Range(Selection, Selection.End(-4121)).Select i`


Its not going passed `objExcel.Range("A5").select` line.

Comment: Not the first time this has [been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14019338/692942). Even had to dup flag [one of my own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39956808/692942) over two years ago. Not surprising seen as though VBScript has been around twenty plus years.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out when I used a test script.

The problem was with xlDirection. The code started working when I started using numbers from the documentation. Also there was an issue was with the `Selection` keyword in `objExcel.Range(Selection, Selection.End(-4121)).Select`. It returned `Object required:'Selection'`. I added `objExel.` to both instances of `Selection`:

`objExcel.Range(objExcel.Selection, objExcel.Selection.End(-4121)).Select`.

It's now working as it should.