# VBScript Add Validation Object runtime error

Tags: vbscript

I have the following VBScript code.

```
    Dim xlapp ' as excel object 
    Dim WSx, WSy ' as excel worksheet 
    Dim x, y ' as workbook 
    Dim fso
    Dim list1
    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim fullpath
    fullpath = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
    
    Set x = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(fullPath & "\File1.xlsx")
    Set y = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(fullPath & "\File2.xlsm") 
    
    Set WSx = x.Worksheets("Sheet1") 
    Set WSy = y.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    WSy.Cells.Clear
    WSx.UsedRange.Copy WSy.Range("A1")
    Set WSx = nothing
    x.Close

WSy.Range("F1").Value="Yes/No"
With WSy.Range("F2").Validation
    .Add xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, , "Option1,Option2"
    .ErrorTitle = "Not a Valid Selection"
    .ErrorMessage = "Please make sure you spelled the item correctly or select the item from the dropdowm menu."
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
End With


Set WSy = nothing  

y.Save 
y.close 
xlapp.quit
```

When executing this code, I get the following error on this line:
.Add xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, , "Option1,Option2"
microsoft vbscript runtime error unknown runtime error

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: How many times does this exact question have to be asked, just search before posting it isn't hard?

Answer (score 0):

You are supplying Excel built-in constants `xlValidateList` and `xlValidAlertStop` but you are not in an Excel macro.

VBScript does not support them, you have to use their actual value. Instead of `xlValidateList` use `3` ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldvtype)). It is common to declare them in your script as contants.

```vb
Option Explicit

Const xlValidateList = 3
'Const xlValidAlertStop = "didn't look this one up"
```

Comment: Yeah it's been [answered multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14019338/692942) before. I've even [answered this myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39956808/692942) on one occasion before realising it was a duplicate and flagging the question.