# How to Autofit Contents all tables in Word Document with vbscript

Tags: automation, vbscript, ms-word

I have a word document with several tables in it with variable column and rows

My Goal is to write a vbscript file which Autofits every table according to its context

Here is a image of the option that I need to enable with by script
[image: 1]

From Something like this [image: 2]

to To Something like this[image: 3]

**My Current code seems to not work:**

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
dim fpath
fpath="D:\tables.docx"
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(fpath)
For Each tbl In objDoc.Tables
    tbl.AutoFitBehavior(wdAutoFitContent)
Next
objDoc.Save
objWord.Quit
```

The above code has no effect on word file, it just opens the file and closes it.
Please Help!

Comment: Vbscript doesn't know the word constants such as `wdAutoFitContent`. Use `option explicit` to get notified of such issues.

Comment: can you explain more about how to achieve what im trying to

Comment: You need to use the [numeric value of wdAutoFitContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa211923(v=office.11)#wdautofitbehavior) in the code like: `tbl.AutoFitBehavior(1)` because as @GeertBellekens said, Vbscript doesn't know the word constants such as `wdAutoFitContent`. Or you can define `wdAutoFitContent` yourself with a value of `1` and use that.

Comment: @Flakes No, what you should do is define them and use the named constants i.e `Const wdAutoFitContent = 1`. Please do not advocate the use of "magic numbers".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting an error \`xlValues\` is not defined when Cells format to the others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019028/getting-an-error-xlvalues-is-not-defined-when-cells-format-to-the-others)

Comment: Also in future to pick up these issues quicker use `Option Explicit` at the top of the script so then undefined values like `wdAutoFitContent` will cause an error to occur.